# How to apply a MongoDB MapReduce?

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce, aggregation-framework

I have the follow SQL sentence and I run It a couple of time by day.

```sql
INSERT INTO `gas_prices` 
    ( `code` , `date` , `lon` , `lat` , `desc` , `price` ) VALUES 
    ('$tCode', '$tDate', $tlon, $tlat, '$tdes', $tprice);
```

I insert 37 records by day, so now, two years ago, the database became so big.

The select sql sentence is this:

```sql
SELECT code, date, lon, lat, desc, price FROM `gas_prices` 
 where (date, code) in 
  (SELECT Max( date ) date, code FROM `gas_prices` GROUP BY code)
 order by lat, lon, code desc;
```

This SQL sentence spend a long time to return data, for this reason I decided to created a cache system in order to return the data more fast.

Right now I have the opportunity to change the database server by another, I like mongoDB, but I would like to know, How can I apply a mapreduce for my system in mongoDB?

Comment: You can also use the MongoDB aggregation framework for this kind of operations.

Comment: And more importantly reference this [documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/sql-aggregation-comparison/) . But your question is not really a question without showing some data first.

Comment: I know you are trying but this still is not a good example. The problem is that you have not tried anything with MongoDB yet. And to actually present a real solution we need to see an example of what your data **actually** looks like. Converting idiomatic SQL statements leads to bad answers. MongoDB and other NoSQL solutions exist because they do things differently than SQL servers do. Your data is important.

Comment: And, I would suggest you do some analysis of your querying and existing system to determine whether trading one technology for another is worth it. You may not have reasonable indexes for your existing SQL solution.

Comment: @neil-lunn Here you can find the real solution on SQL database [link](http://anunciosesena.com/index.php?option=com_seseanuncio&view=gasolina&Itemid=93). The mobile App takes this data too.

Comment: @gMargarita Linking to external Websites is not a valid source here. You need to provide something that people can work with otherwise you simply do not have a question to ask. And you will get not answers. Of worth anyway.